# Search a nested List in C#

Tags: c#, tree, nested, structure

I have a list of object

```
public class DebtorTreeModel {

        public int ID { get; set; }      
        public string text { get; set; }
        public int  ParentID { get; set; }
        public int BillingParentID { get; set; }
        public int ReportingParentID { get; set; }
        public bool HasChildren { get; set; }


        public List<DebtorTreeModel> items { get; set; }


    }
```

I will be adding nodes based on this object as in a tree structure.
My code require to add child node to an inner node , but i am unable to find the inner node , I use

```
 List<DebtorTreeModel> rootDebtorNode  ;  //This list has been loaded with all parent nodes though
 rootDebtorNode.Find(t => t.ID == debtChild.BillingParentId).items.Add(debtorTreeModelChild);
```

The last  line of code fails to fetch that particualr inner node , even if it exists, can some one help

Comment: We can't help without a minimal, reproducible example. You need to give an example of a list that makes the `Find` fail.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment of needing a working example, to point you in the right direction i would look at Dijkstra’s Algorithm and the graph data structure. There are plenty of c# examples on this structure. For example

http://blog.boxofbolts.com/dotnet/graphs/2015/08/31/working_with_graph_data_structures_dot_net/

https://github.com/YaccConstructor/QuickGraph

My assumption is this is what you are attempting to do based off your example. Happy to help with a more detailed problem.